# Render multiple textures in one shader pass

Tags: opengl-es, branch, webgl

Could it be faster in WebGL to render multiple textures in one pass like:

```
varying float materialIndex;
varying vec2 textureCoord; 

uniform sampler2D textureSampler1;
uniform sampler2D textureSampler2;
uniform sampler2D textureSampler3;
uniform sampler2D textureSampler4;

vec4 getMaterial(float materialId, textureCoord) {
    vec4 color;

    if (materialId == 1.0)
    {
        color = texture2D( textureSampler1, textureCoord );
    }
    else if (materialId == 2.0)
    {
        color = texture2D( textureSampler2, textureCoord );
    }
    else if (materialId == 3.0)
    {
        color = texture2D( textureSampler3, textureCoord );
    }
    else
    {
        color = texture2D( textureSampler4, textureCoord );
    }

    return color;
}

void main()               
{                  
    vec4 color = getMaterial(materialIndex, textureCoord);
    gl_FragColor = color;        
}
```

Because this will save one fourth of the instructions the CPU has to send to the GPU, beside the extra information the vertex shader has to pass along, wouldn't it still be faster in most cases than do 4x as much program calls, I've read that even in opengl the biggest performance hit is the cpu by far, and i bet this is even more the case for Webgl. Or would this maybe be faster?

```
uniform float materialIndex;
varying vec2 textureCoord; 

uniform sampler2D textureSampler1;
uniform sampler2D textureSampler2;
uniform sampler2D textureSampler3;
uniform sampler2D textureSampler4;


void main()               
{                  
    vec4 color = getMaterial(materialIndex, textureCoord);
    gl_FragColor = color;        
}
```

Or is changing a functional uniform just as bad as just loading a new shader with respect to the number of calls the CPU has to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Batching is important, yes. But it's not *that* important. Especially when confronted with the possibility that a some hardware could sample from *all four textures*, no matter what.

In the varying case, the compiler has no idea how the value varies. Therefore, it will assume that any fragment could get any value. So it must do a runtime branch for everything. And due to the cost of conditional branches, the compiler will usually attempt to avoid doing 4 consecutive conditional branches by simply executing all available paths and using the non-branching logic to compute the final result.

Your uniform case is not safe from such "optimizations" either, as some older hardware is functionally incapable of doing conditional branching over important instructions at all. So they have no choice but to either recompile your shader every time you change a uniform (and that's not hyperbole; NVIDIA compilers on old hardware actually did that) or do all 4 texture accesses.

Oh, and another thing: the `texture2D` function becomes undefined when in non-uniform control flow (like in a conditionally executed block). Now, it probably won't hurt you here because of how you're using it. But generally speaking, you would need to either use explicit gradients or remove your texture access functions from the conditional blocks. And WebGL does not have gradient texture functions, as I recall.

In short, just change the texture and render again. Even in JavaScript, that's not going to kill your performance as much as potentially doing 4 texture accesses. As long as you're only binding a texture between renders (ie: you're not changing programs or other state), and you're observing good practice (rendering as much as you reasonably can between state changes) you should be relatively OK.